# Meaning of それどうする気

Tags: set-phrases

Yamada has just collected a lot of insects and is asked:

> 「それどうする気?」

I'm guessing this is a set phrase along the lines of "What were you thinking?". I can't get any sense out of a literal translation.

I keep seeing this pairing of どう and する in things I can't translate literally e.g. どうしたの "what's the matter?". Is there some kind of rule I can apply that will help me understand these phrases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

それどうする気 means それをどうするつもり and it is translated as "What are you going to do with it?". And どうする? is translated as "What would you do?".

A verb + 気 means "intention to verb". For example, 彼にそのことを話すきなの?(Are you going to tell him that thing?).

Answer (score 0):

する is a verb meaning "to do".
どう means "how".
気 in this case means "intention".

So どうする気? means "what do you intend to do?".